# Как увеличить толщину ProgressBar в kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Нужно увеличить толщину ProgressBar, чтобы было как на примере[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

kv файл:

```
WidgetsExample:

<WidgetsExample>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:(.57, .51, .59,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "10dp"
    Label:
        text: "You have not gambled for"
        size_hint: 1,.2
    ProgressBar:
        size_hint:None,None
        width: "100dp"
        height: "50dp"
```

Comment: А сейчас как выглядит? И height не работает?

Comment: @CrazyElf неа, работает только ширина